# Snowflake emoji is not showing correctly on browser

Tags: html, css, emoji

I am trying to show the snowflake emoji, unicode `U+2744`, which when I do using CSS, is:

```
[emoji='snowflake']:after {
    content: '\2744';
}
```

However, it shows this emoji: ❄ - screenshot [image]

If I copy the emoji from another source, it shows: ❄️️ - screenshot [image]

[Source](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) for how this emoji should look on browser.

Which in my IDE looks like: [image]

Why does it happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: When I look at this in the iOS app, I see both as the same snowflake...

Comment: @jonrsharpe correct. It seems like this is a browser only issue

Comment: Hi Amit and @jonrsharpe These emojis might not be consistent on non-apple devices: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5065335?tstart=0

Comment: I guess my point was really that you need to show screenshots.

Comment: I see two thimes the same icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJt4F.png

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn You are seeing the windows icon, not the browser icon. please see reference source in the question.

Comment: If it is causing such a problem, then why can't you just use a picture instead.

Comment: Because images suck. This is 4 bytes compared to an image size

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest adding a background-image to your [emoji='snowflake']:after instead.

You can get a free to use snowflake icon here:

https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=snowflake&license=2&price=free

Comment: I prefer using the native icons on the devices (iphone, android, browser) instead of having an image. It renders faster, it takes less space in the app, and does not scale well (if not svg)